# Appharbor build error on default app from VS2015

Tags: appharbor

Using VS Community 2015 and created a default web MVC app that works fine locally but Appharbor gave this error on build

error ASPRUNTIME: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\temp\vr4kg55i.jlt\output_PublishedWebsites\TestAppharbor\bin\roslyn\csc.exe'.

Is AppHarbor ready for the latest .NET app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem and here is what I found: [appharbor support](https://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/78633-cant-build-aspnet-mvc-project-generated-from-vstudio-2015-enterprise#comment_37577678).

As suggested, adding this to the end of the web prject .csproj file, fixed the error:

```
...
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>
    if not exist "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Roslyn" md "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Roslyn"
  start /MIN xcopy /s /y /R "$(OutDir)roslyn\*.*" "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Roslyn"
  </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```